# value weighted portfolio returns per portfolio

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with dates, returns, portfolio's and market caps for a list of stocks. I want to calculate the value weighted market returns per month in my data and per portfolio.

```
date        ret     portf   mkval
1982-03-31  0.02    3.0     2000
1982-04-30  0.05    2.0     500
1982-05-31  0.10    1.0     3000
1982-03-31  0.05    3.0     4000
1982-04-30  0.20    3.0     700
1982-05-31  0.02    2.0     2000
1982-05-31  0.08    1.0     5000
```

This data should yield the following output:

```
date         portf   equal_w_ret
1982-03-31   3.0     0.04
1982-04-30   2.0     0.05
1982-04-30   3.0     0.20
1982-05-31   1.0     0.0875
1982-05-31   2.0     0.02
```

Here, the first row is calculated as: (2000/(2000+4000))*(1+0.02)+(4000/(2000+4000))*(1+0.05)-1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up the data

```
data = { 'date' : ['1982-03-31','1982-04-30','1982-05-31','1982-03-31','1982-04-30','1982-05-31','1982-05-31'],
    'ret' : [0.02,0.05,0.10,0.05,0.20,0.02,0.08],
    'portf' : [3.0,2.0,1.0,3.0,3.0,2.0,1.0],
    'mkval' : [2000,500,3000,4000,700,2000,5000]}
```

Now make the data into a dataframe and prepare the output dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfout = pd.DataFrame()
```

The interesting bit!  Groupby the date and portfolio number and then do the calculation by row.  Then make a dataframe that is the summary for that row and put it in the output dataframe

```
for group, subdf in df.groupby(['date','portf']):
    subdf['wret'] = (subdf['mkval'] * ( 1 + subdf['ret']))/subdf['mkval'].sum()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'data' : [group[0]],'portf':[group[1]],'equal_w_ret':[subdf['wret'].sum() - 1]})
    dfout = dfout.append(df2)
```

This makes

```
    data        portf   equal_w_ret
0   1982-03-31  3.0     0.0400
0   1982-04-30  2.0     0.0500
0   1982-04-30  3.0     0.2000
0   1982-05-31  1.0     0.0875
0   1982-05-31  2.0     0.0200
```